# Execute a stored procedure in Oracle 21C having an input parameter as an array

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Before posting the question, I tried to find something similar to what I have, but without success.

Here I have everything, the creation of types, the creation of the table, the insertion of values, the creation of procedure, everything works except the part when I try to call the procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_serial AS TABLE OF VARCHAR(20)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ITEM_DATA AS OBJECT
(
    ITEM_CODE VARCHAR2 (50),
    serial array_serial,
    notes VARCHAR2 (1000)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE obj_good_array AS VARRAY(500) OF ITEM_DATA;

CREATE  TABLE item_data_table 
(
    item_id NUMBER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    item_data obj_good_array
);
```

Inserting the data

```
DECLARE
    item_data_obj obj_good_array;
BEGIN
    item_data_obj := obj_good_array();
    item_data_obj.extend;
    item_data_obj(1) := ITEM_DATA(
        'ABC123',
        array_serial('Serial1', 'Serial2', 'Serial3'),
        'Sample notes for item ABC123'
    );

    INSERT INTO item_data_table (item_data) VALUES (item_data_obj);
    COMMIT;
END;
/

DECLARE
    item_data_obj obj_good_array;
BEGIN
    item_data_obj := obj_good_array();
    item_data_obj.extend;
    item_data_obj(1) := ITEM_DATA(
        'XYZ789',
        array_serial('Serial4', 'Serial5', 'Serial6'),
        'Sample notes for item XYZ789'
    );
 
    INSERT INTO item_data_table (item_data) VALUES (item_data_obj);
    COMMIT;
END;
/

select * from item_data_table;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE process_items (
    p_item_list IN obj_good_array
) AS
BEGIN
  
    FOR i IN 1..p_item_list.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item Code: ' || p_item_list(i).ITEM_CODE);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Notes: ' || p_item_list(i).notes);
        
        FOR j IN 1..p_item_list(i).serial.COUNT LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Serial ' || j || ': ' || p_item_list(i).serial(j));
        END LOOP;
        
    END LOOP;
END process_items;
/
```

Calling the procedure in this way is not working. This is the error:

> ORA-02315: incorrect number of arguments for default constructor

Code:

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
    item_data_variable obj_good_array; -- Declare the obj_good_array variable
BEGIN
 
    SELECT CAST(MULTISET(
        SELECT item_data
        FROM item_data_table
    ) AS obj_good_array) INTO item_data_variable FROM dual;

    process_items(item_data_variable);
END;
/
```

This should be the output:

```
Item Code: ABC123
Notes: Sample notes for item ABC123
Serial 1: Serial1
Serial 2: Serial2
Serial 3: Serial3

Item Code: XYZ789
Notes: Sample notes for item XYZ789
Serial 1: Serial4
Serial 2: Serial5
Serial 3: Serial6
```

Can you please help how to call this stored procedure?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you do not have a nested table, you have a `VARRAY`.

Secondly, you can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  item_data_variable obj_good_array; -- Declare the obj_good_array variable
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();

  FOR rw IN (SELECT * FROM item_data_table) LOOP
    process_items(rw.item_data);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> Item Code: ABC123
> Notes: Sample notes for item ABC123
> Serial 1: Serial1
> Serial 2: Serial2
> Serial 3: Serial3
> Item Code: XYZ789
> Notes: Sample notes for item XYZ789
> Serial 1: Serial4
> Serial 2: Serial5
> Serial 3: Serial6
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cqAJrXuo)